# Overriding a Git-Send-Email to-cmd option

Tags: git, email, sendmail

We use the `git send-email` command in our workflow to deliver patches. There is a small script that determines which maintainer to deliver it to (based on which files were edited), so we have all set the `sendemail.tocmd` option to point to that script, using the following command:

```
git config --global sendemail.tocmd ~/scripts/git-send-email-to-cmd.sh
```

There are occasional edge cases when we want to send the code to a different maintainer than it would normally be sent to. But if we specify that maintainer with the `--to` flag (as below), then the email gets sent to both the normal maintainer (chosen by the script) and the one we specify.

```
git send-email --to=maintainer@company.com 0001-*.patch
```

If we want to send it *only* to the specified maintainer, the only option we've been able to find is to unset the `sendemail.tocmd` option, execute the command above, and then re-set the option when finished.

Is there a flag that tells send-email to bypass the normal to-cmd?

Comment: I think this can be accomplished by specifiying `--to-cmd` too? (overwrite the default behavior)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> the only option we've been able to find is to unset the sendemail.tocmd option, execute the command above, and then re-set the option when finished.

Generally, you can unset a config for one command with a `-c "config="` `git` parameter:

```
git -c "sendemail.tocmd=" send-email --to=maintainer@company.com 0001-*.patch
```

If not possible, as commented, the [`--to-cmd`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-send-email#Documentation/git-send-email.txt---to-cmdltcommandgt) option would take precedence over `sendemail.tocmd` anyway.